# Node process listening on port which is already used by non node process(c++)

Tags: node.js, port

I have written c++ application which is listening on port 5000. I also have node application in which I have created server connection using net module which is listening on the same port 5000. In such scenario I want my node application to throw error as EADDRINUSE instead of listening the port 5000.Is there any solution in node to handle the scenario?

Comment: And it doesn't now? *How* do you "listen" to the ports? Can you perhaps try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of both programs?

Comment: `bind` will fail if the port is in use.

Comment: If one application listens on port 5000 of a particular interface (say "127.0.0.1", the loopback interface), it's acceptable for another process to listen on port 5000 of another interface (for instance the (W)LAN interface). I don't think you can stop that behaviour.